# Java: Why ConcurrentModificationException doesnt occur while using Stream+Iterator?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, iterator, java-stream

I was reading some info about iterators, enumeration, etc. So I tested some code to check everything out.

**First one example:**

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("5");
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
list.remove("1");
iterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

**This code makes the correct and expected output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

**But when I tested the same code with only 1 change** `list.iterator()` -> `list.stream().iterator()`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("5");
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
Iterator<String> iterator = list.stream().iterator();
list.remove("1");
iterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

**The result was:**

```
5
2
3
```

**My main aim is to understand:**

1. Why is this happens?
2. What magic makes only one `stream()` method?
3. What are the advantages and disadvantages of using `stream().iterator`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#stream()), the API internally calls [`spliterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#spliterator()), which it similar to [`iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#iterator()).

For [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html), the returned [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Spliterator.html) / [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html) uses an `expectedModCount` field to compare to the `modCount` field of the list, to check if the list has been modified.

The implementation of `Iterator` initializes the `expectedModCount` field when the iterator is created.

The implementation of `Spliterator` defers that initialization until the first element is taken from the `Spliterator`.

Which means that it allows modification of the list between the call to `stream()` and the call to the terminal operation that actually starts pulling data from the stream.

Comment: These are technical (implementation) details. The more important aspect is that `ArrayList`’s `stream()` method returns a [late-binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#binding) `Stream`. It also has been specified in [the Non-interference section of the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference): “*For well-behaved stream sources, the source can be modified before the terminal operation commences and those modifications will be reflected in the covered elements.*” with example…